# Renewing certificate on server with Let's Encrypt when first issued with docker

Tags: nginx, ssl, amazon-ec2, django, letsencrypt

I am running a dockerized django on an EC2 instance. I configured nginx in a docker container and got a certificate also in a docker container. (I followed this guide: https://www.humankode.com/ssl/how-to-set-up-free-ssl-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-using-docker-and-nginx)

The problem is that I deviated from the tutorial and when I had my certificates I copied them to the server to `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com$`. I created with my certs with this command:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm -v /docker-volumes/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt -v /docker-volumes/var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt -v /docker/letsencrypt-docker-nginx/src/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-site:/data/letsencrypt -v "/docker-volumes/var/log/letsencrypt:/var/log/letsencrypt" \
certbot/certbot certonly --webroot --email youremail@domain.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --webroot-path=/data/letsencrypt -d mydomain
```

Now I want to set up an automatic renewal but I think my structure is messed up.

When I try with `certbot certonly --standalone --staging -d mydomain`

I get `live directory exists for mydomain` but nothing gets renewed.

When I try with `sudo certbot certonly --nginx --staging -d mydomain` I get `nginx: [error] invalid PID number`.

I'm not quite sure what to do from here. Also I don't know if it's a problem that my nginx runs in a docker container on the server and I request the certificates for my server.

Any help or suggestions are very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

My nginx config and my docker compose:

```
production-nginx-container:
    container_name: 'production-nginx-container'
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes: ##The following files are found on AWS EC2 instance.
      - /etc/nginx-conf/myconf.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/privkey.pem
    depends_on:
      - django
```

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.de;
    charset utf-8;
    ssl_stapling off;
    ssl_stapling_verify off;

    ssl_certificate            /etc/letsencrypt/live/heatbe.at/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.de/privkey.pem;


    set $my_host $http_host;
    if ($http_host = "mydomain.de") {
          set $my_host "mydomain.de";
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $my_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}

server {
        listen 80 ;
        server_name mydomain.de;
        return 301 https://mydomain.de$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 80 ;
        server_name www.mydomain.de;
        return 301 https://mydomain.de$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ;
        server_name www.mydomain.de;
        return 301 https://mydomain.de$request_uri;
        ssl_stapling off;
        ssl_stapling_verify off;

        ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.de/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.de/privkey.pem;
}
```